# Symfony Ajax Controller Handler, always fires jQuery error function

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am really new with Symfony framework I am just trying to implement a simple ajax example:

Routing:

```
DartDartBundle_data_user:
    pattern:  /data/user
    defaults: { _controller: DartDartBundle:Data:user }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

DataController:

```
namespace Dart\DartBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function userAction(){      
        $content = array('success' => true, 'name' => 'luis');
        $response = new JsonResponse($content,200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
    return $response;
    }
}
```

And the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url : 'http://symfony.dartintelligence.com/app_dev.php/data/user',
    success : function(data){
        console.log("OK");
        console.log(data);  
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){   
        console.log("SOME ERROR OCURRED");
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
});
```

But it always fires the error function. I don't know why. I've try without specifying jston dataType and using Response instead of JsonResponse.

I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: if you enter 'http://symfony.dartintelligence.com/app_dev.php/data/user' into your browser, do you get a valid json output? also, what is the error that is returned?

Comment: In the routing you are restricting the Ajax call to 'POST' and in javascript you are issuing a GET. Try changing to $.ajax{type:'POST'...

Comment: Yep, both are right. If I use browser it gives me the expected results (if I set up it as GET method). And sorry I mixed things up, I've tried method restricted GET or POST and trying both Ajax calls using GET or POST with the same result. Error handler fires.

Comment: Can you post the text of the error?

Comment: Screen capture of Firebug with the "error" https://www.dropbox.com/s/g77xbb9d2nyl78e/screen_capture_20131120.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

Route is configured as POST - only

The Ajax request is a GET request

try to remove the requirement

**Second**

Try to access the url directly in your browser to check if you configured the path right and you can access the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as I said I mixed up things because I was trying both methods, GET and POST. But no luck. I am still getting the same error using both methods, its returns status 200 but it fires error handler of jQuery Ajax callback. No idea why.

Comment: The Firebug screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g77xbb9d2nyl78e/screen_capture_20131120.png

Comment: And accessing the url directly works, yep: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3lyf5zgw4djoi83/screen_capture_20131120_2.png. Ajax is still having the same problem :(

Comment: Is the Ajax request from the same origin or is this a cross site request ? If you open the request in firebug (arrow sign) what informations can you read out of it (header -> response)

Answer (score 0):

The request is made from the same server but with a different domain. The request is not using any vhost or domain, its uses server's ip and the htdocs folder.

Symfony is placed in a folder which has a vhost alias and its accessed using a domain (i.e. symfony.dartintelligence.com/app_dev.php/data/user). The folder in the server is inside /DART root folder. So its ./DART/symfony....

The firebug info for either of the methods. For instance, for GET method:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9o6kbsnlyhibxo/screen_capture_20131120_GET_method.png